# How to shutdown peripheral

Tags: shutdown, battery, peripherals

I was helping someone on the Italian help service investigating a problem of battery draining when the computer is shut down.

This problem appears only when shutting down from Lubuntu, not from Windows.

And the following question came to my mind.

Is there a way in (*)Ubuntu to selectively shutdown peripherals (maybe on reboot)?

So to say, a flag in some configuration files, or some kernel parameters on boot, that make the video card/network card/wireless card/bluetooth card/disks/etc. not wake up at all?